# UnitTask error trying to use Microsoft.Build.Evaluation

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

have the following code inside my CSProj file:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="HelloWorld" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
             AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">

    <Task>
      <!--Microsoft.Build.dll-->            
      <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Evaluation" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[                        
              var p = new Project("$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)");
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
```

in my AfterBuild I call it like this:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <HelloWorld />
  </Target>
```

The error I am getting is:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Project' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Referring to var p = new **Project**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include Microsoft.Build reference in the task can fix that issue. (The Microsoft.Build.dll reference need to be added to your project firstly)

```
<Task>
      <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build"/>      
      <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Evaluation" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[                        
              var p = new Project("$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)");
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
```

Comment: This solve that issue, thank you, now I am getting an error: 
System.InvalidOperationException: An equivalent project (a project with the same global properties and tools version) is already present in the project collection, with the path "C:\Users\stal\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\MyClassLibrary\MyClassLibrary.csproj". To load an equivalent into this project collection, unload this project first.